# php pagination row count is not following the set limit

Tags: php, datatables, pagination, row, limit

Can someone please help me? I'm really frustrated right now because the count in this table is 16, even though I set the limit to 10 and below shows that it's showing 1-10 records out of 26 entries. The table I used in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frcSo.png) is *datatable*.

As you can see I have already set the max limit as:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'limit'     => $limit,
    'maxLimit'  => $limit
];
$workstations = $this->paginate($result);
```

Comment: Are you using some framework? What is it? Or can you post the implementation of the paginate function?

Comment: yes im using cakephp